# Suppose $a,b ∈ N$. Then $ a = \text{lcm}(a,b) \iff b|a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The fact that this is true seems clear to me. But I'm not quite sure how to write a formal proof. Obviously if $a$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, then a will be divisible by $b$. How would I go about expressing this idea in the form of a proof?

I know you begin by proving:

$a=\text{lcm}(a,b) \rightarrow b|a$

Then prove:

$b|a \rightarrow a=\text{lcm}(a,b)$

I imagine there is a simple way to express the $\text{lcm}$ that may help.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

If $a = \text{lcm}(a,b)$, then in particular $a$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, and so $b \mid a$.

The other way: Suppose $b \mid a$. Since we also have $a \mid a$, we get that $a$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. Hence, $ \text{lcm}(a,b) \leq a$. Also, since $a \mid \text{lcm}(a,b)$, we get $a \leq \text{lcm}(a,b)$, so $a = \text{lcm}(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definitions of $\operatorname{lcm}$ and $\gcd$ this is a simple task:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} = a \iff \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)} = 1 \iff b = \gcd(a,b) \iff b|a
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is $lcd(a,b)$?

Comment: @L.F. A typo :) I suppose LCD would be the least common divisor, which would be 1.

Comment: Well $\frac{1}{n}$ is also a common divisor where $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ :P

Answer (score 0):

If $b\mid a \to a = kb \to \text{lcm}(a,b) = \text{lcm}(kb,b) = b\text{lcm}(k,1) = bk = a$, and the other direction is quite clear.